# Find distinct values from column of datatable in c# and store distinct values in variables

Tags: c#-4.0

i want to find distinct values from a column of datatable in c# and also want to store all these distinct values in variables

```
  DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
  OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from clubbb ", con);
            da.Fill(dtable, "clubbb");
            int toto = bdtable.AsEnumerable().Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: try use query: SELECT DISTINCT column from clubbb

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the interface `IEqualityComparer<DataRow>` methods to provide the way the `Distinct` method will use to know whether 2 rows are duplicate or not. This can be achieved with a class like this:

```
public class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        // your custom equality logic here
    }
    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        // return hash code depending on your distinct criteria
    }
}
```

Then change the call you made:

```
int toto = bdtable.AsEnumerable().Distinct(new CustomComparer()).Count();
```

I had similar problem, and in my case I needed to know distinct values of specific column, so I passed the name of this column to the custom comparer I implemented, so that `GetHashCode` will return identical hash codes for duplicate values.

You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps :)